# how to login as admin and normal employee had different side menu

Tags: iframe, ionic-framework, side-menu

I would like to ask how to do login to admin account and login to normal account and make them had different side menu by using iFrames ,ionic and calling the urls.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the users in a DB (by userID, I assume).
   In the users DB, create a "level" row. When someone signs up, make your app give the user's DB entry "level" row a "none" or "1" value, if you intend to have more than just regular users and admins. You can explicitly give yourself a "true" or "2" value later on.
2. When user is logged in, pull the row "level" or whatever you decided to name it from their DB entry, and store it in a variable. You could create a new typescript in the app folder, export the var from there. Then just import the file in other pages when needed. For this example, lets say that the var is called "usrLvl".
3. Lastly, you can either create two different tabs or and call *ngIf on their content, or if you just want to have a couple of different buttons for admin, call *ngIf on the buttons. It'd look something like this

   ```
   <ion-buttons right *ngIf="usrLvl == 2">
     <button ion-button (click)="adminButtonFunction();">Admin button</button>
   </ion-buttons>
   ```

I think that's how you could go about doing it